# Where is the sound file of Installer success stored?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, alert

I've tracked `Installer.app` to be located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/` but I can't find the sound that plays after a successful installation.

I've looked at the following paths:

- `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Install.framework`
- `/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app`
- `/System/Library/Sounds`

Where is that sound file located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you are looking for (on El Capitan) is located in: `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system/`

Specifically, the file is `burn complete.aif` (or `burn failed.aif`, they're identical).

Older versions of OS X (unknown when it changed) have it at ([source](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/change-the-tritone-installation-complete-sound.524273/)):
`/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/SystemSounds/system/`

Comment: Thanks! I would like to know how you tracked this down so I can add it to my mental tools.

Comment: @radj Looked near the old path which was mentioned in that link (I just updated). Without that information, a common technique for finding files is typing a file type into Finder (if indexed), or running `find [DIR] -type f -name '*.[FILE_EXT]'` in Terminal, using your desired directory and file extension.

Answer (score -1):

The install success sound is usually just your default system notification sound (i.e., Glass or whatever you have set).

If you want to set a custom sound, make sure it's in AIFF format, place it in one of these locations and choose the sound from System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects

```
/System/Library/Sounds/
/Library/Sounds/
/Users/< username >/Library/Sounds/
```

Comment: Can also be *.m4r (MP4 Ringtone Format)

Comment: I checked the system sounds but it's not any of them. The system sounds are also listed in my initial question in the path `/System/Library/Sounds`